Qué sería mejor; usar try catch o condiciones if?
De una aplicación Windows Form en C#, hecha para el control de asistenacia mediante un biométrico de huella dactilar, ha presentado muy esporádicamente que algunos empleados no se les registra su entrada; les estoy hablando de que esto se presenta de una a dos veces por mes.
El procedimiento es que cuando se pasa por el biométrico el dedo, primero guardo el registro y después mando un aviso de voz con el SpeechSynthesizer.
Sin embargo, por la premura del tiempo nunca hice la validación para verificar que se haya grabado correctamente el registro; ya sé que me van a decir que eso es primordial; me disculpo por este error.
Ahora les pregunto; cuál seria la forma más correcta y segura para verificar que se haya guardado el registro..... tengo 2 opciones.
Primera opción:
try
{
   bool Bnuevo = buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida(horaSalida, estatusSalida, 1,justificante,  IDRegistro, DateTime.Now);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox("Por favor, Vuelva a registrar su entrada";)
}

Segunda opción:
bool Bnuevo = buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida(horaSalida, estatusSalida, 1,justificante, IDRegistro, DateTime.Now);
if (Bnuevo == false)
{
   MessageBox("Por favor, Vuelva a registrar su entrada";)
}

En espera a sus comentarios, respuestas y críticas constructivas, reciban saludos cordiales.
Muchas Gracias.

si la segunda funciona, porque usar la primera??? o ActualizaSalida devuelve una excepcion???

Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas.

Está pregunta no está basada en opiniones, más bien puede usarse para una mejor comprensión de como usar las excepciones

@Japv no debiera ser basada en opiniones, pero el AP lo ha hecho así. Hasta dice "pero necesito realmente sus opiniones por favor". Seguro editando la pregunta se puede quitar ese matiz y hacerla válida para el sitio.

@jachguate siguiendo tu observación acabo de editar la publicación y quitar del texto la parte "conflictiva"

No sé cuál sea mejor, pero sí que usar excepciones es peor en términos de rendimiento. En C# podes encontrar por ejemplo int.Parse que lanza una excepción y int.TryParse que devuelve verdadero si el string es un número válido

Hola Sergio podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado gracias

Tus ejemplos son muy diferente.  No realizan la misma idea.
El primero con "try/catch" mostrará la mensaje cuando ocurre cualquier Exception en buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida().  Esta excepción podría ser la que deseas, o cualquier otra excepción en (o debajo) buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida().
El segundo con "if" solo mostrará la mensaje cuando buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida() funciona correctamente y devuelve un valor de "false".  Si hay una excepción la mensaje no aparecerá.
Sin embargo, creo en utilizar excepciones únicamente para cosas que son excepcionales.  Para me, no registrando una entrada no es exceptional, es simple una condición humana.
Finalmente, "(Bnuevo == false)" es una mala practica.  Sólo necesitas escribir "(!Bnuevo)"

coincido con esta respuesta.. menos con "(Bnuevo == false)" es una mala practica.. porque seria una mala practica????

@gbianchi La declaración "if" toma una expresión booleana. Bneuvo es una variable booleana.    Al escribir "if (Bnuevo == false)", estás comparando un valor booleano con booleano para crear un resultado booleano, que luego se usa en "if".   Pero "if (!Bnuevo)" usa el valor directamente (y es más corto de teclear!).   Sin embargo, el compilador de C# optimizará "Bnuevo == false" para que sea "!Bnuevo".

@gbianchi Pero en otros lenguajes (por ejemplo, C o C++), puede realizar asignaciones en declaraciones "if".   Por lo tanto, "if(Bnuevo = false)" es una declaración válida, pero asigna false a Bnuevo y nunca ejecuta el código "if () {... }".   Errores como este pueden ser difíciles de depurar, por lo que es mejor adoptar un estilo que los evite, especialmente si trabaja con varios idiomas.

eso no lo hace una mala practica para nada... lo de C es un error y no tiene nada que ver...

@gbianchi En mi carrera he trabajado con al menos 15 idiomas diferentes. Algunos permiten asignaciones en "if", otros no.   Pero mi escritura no es perfecta, por lo que es posible que yo escriba mal "==" como "=". Adoptar un estilo coherente que evite asignaciones en un "if" significa que minimizo dichos errores.

@PeterM coincido con gbianchi al decir que no es una mala práctica, además en c# no existe ese problema que si tiene c++

Yo no diría que el if (x == false) es una mala práctica, pero si es un rastro definitivo de quién está aún en su infancia booleana :D. El if (!x) no solo es más legible y claro solo sino, sobre todo, si se comienza a llenar de and's y or's esa condición.
No es lo mismo leer if (autorizado == true & anulado == false) que if (autorizado & !anulado), pero bueno... para los gustos los colores.

bool? x = null;if(false == x){ Console.WriteLine ("false");} else {Console.WriteLine ("not false");} "nullable bools"

Las excepciones deben usarse para situaciones que los programadores no podemos controlar, por ejemplo, estamos tratando de acceder a un servidor de base de datos y en el local donde está ubicado ese servidor se va la corriente, en este caso se usa una excepción para avisarnos que no hemos podido conectarnos al servidor por determinada razón, también usamos excepciones a la hora de trabajar con ficheros para garantizar por ejemplo que si ocurre un error de lectura o escritura el programa no colapse, y garantizar también ocurra lo que ocurra que el fichero termine cerrado, hay muchos otros ejemplos en que se pueden aplicar las excepciones. Ahora bien usar las excepciones "porque sí" está mal, de hecho siempre que puedas evitarlas pues evítalas, ya que como quiera que sea es una interrupción brusca en tu aplicación. Trata de validar lo más que puedas(Programación defensiva). No hace falta usar excepciones para determinar si un campo está vacío o no cumple con determinada longitud. En tu ejemplo si podrías usar excepciones ya que accedes a la base de datos y por muy improbable que parezca pudiera irse la corriente o bien romperse la tarjeta de red del servidor o cualquier otra situación que no puedas controlar(son casos improbables, pero perfectamente posibles). Por otra parte si lo que pretendes hacer no tiene nada que ver con acceder a la base de datos pues evita usar excepciones.

Creo que deberia ser una mezcla, si se cae buscaempleado no tienes como saberlo (no que retorne un false sino una excepcion)
try
{
   bool Bnuevo = buscaEmpleadoS.ActualizaSalida(horaSalida, estatusSalida, 1,justificante,  IDRegistro, DateTime.Now);
 if (Bnuevo == false)
 {
   MessageBox("Por favor, Vuelva a registrar su entrada";)
 }
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox("Ha ocurrido un problema interno. Por favor, Vuelva a registrar su entrada";)
}

